Monorepo with Deno and node.js (vite) with shared packages, what is the setup?
I am trying to set up a Deno / Nodejs monorepo with some shared packages meant to be used in both environments:
repo/
├── packages/ (shared with frontend and backend)
├── backend/ (Deno)
└── frontend/ (Vite, e.g. node.js environment)

The shared packages are written in Typescript, and some of them depends on each other.
Importing the packages into the Deno backend is straightforward. You can just reference the files directly, e.g. import {x} from "../packages/my-package/somefile.ts" or using import maps in deno.jsonc of the consuming Deno code.
Referencing .ts files also sort of works in the vite frontend, all though there is a lot of moving parts in the tsconfig.json and vite.config.mts files which I will not try to document here (it was trial-and-error). I can import functions and some types. However, it does not give me full type-safety. Some type-constraints are ignored, e.g. some types becomes any. I have tried several permutations of settings with no luck.
A fix might be to add a build step to the packages. This should ensure all relevant type information is exported. Thus the frontend can import them as regular compiled modules, while the Deno packages can just reference the ts files as before.
Does anyone have experience with doing so or recommendations how to set up a monorepo like the one mentioned?
Note: Deno has a deno-to-node (dnt) transformer https://deno.com/learn/modules, that can run a build process. I am wondering if this could be used for the build process, instead of tsc.
